# A generic VBscript function to connect to any database and execute any SQL query

Tags: vbscript, adodb

the function should just take connection string and a SQL query as input and it should connect to any database(SQL, ORACLE, SYBASE, MS ACCESS) and execute any query which i have passed as the parameters to the function.

I have written the below function for that task, Can you please check this once and tell me is this correct or pls tell me if i am wrong anywhere.

#

```
Public Function ConnectDB (strCon, strQuery)
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objConnection.Open strCon

objRecordSet.Open strQuery,objConnection 
objRecordSet.MoveFirst
Do Until objRecordset.EOF
Msgbox "Number of records: " & objRecordset.RecordCount 
Msgbox objRecordset(0)
Msgbox objRecordset(1)
    objRecordset.MoveNext
Loop
objRecordSet.Close
objConnection.Close
Set objConnection = Nothing
Set objRecordSet = Nothing
End Function
```

#

```
Call ConnectDB ("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & _ 
            "Data Source = inventory.mdb","SELECT * FROM EMP ORDER BY EMPName")
```

**UPDATE:**
Thank you so much for the replies.

Actually i have been asked to write a function which performs the task of connecting to any database and executing any query(given by user) in that connected database.

I have started to learn VBScript and want to have indepth knowledge of writing functions. Ekkehard horner can you please tell me where can i read to get know all about routines(functions and sub procedure). Presently, i have only the basic idea on routines and i referred MSDN, where they have given only basic information. Please help me where to study more about routines. It is so difficult to write programs without knowing about them correctly.

Hi Sanpaco, below is the class i wrote. Please check it once and let me know the corrections.
I am very new to VBScript.Suggest me ways to improve my programming knowledge.

```
Class DBCommunicator
Public Function DBConnect(StrCon)
Option Eplicit
Dim oConn
set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConn.Open Strcon
Function DBConnect = True
End Function

Public Function QueryDB(StrQuery)
Option Eplicit
Dim oRst, oField
set oRst = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
oRst.Open "StrQuery", oConn
Do Until oRst.EOF   
For each oField in oRst.Fields        
Print oField.Name & " = " & oField.Value    
Next
oRst.MoveNext
loop

Public Function DBdisConnect
oRst.close
oConn.close
End Function
End Class

########################################

Option Explicit
Dim strResult
strResult=DBCommunicator.DBConnect("<<Connection String of any database User want to connect>>")
    If strResult<>True Then
        wscript.echo "DB Connection Failed"

    End If
DBCommunicator.QueryDB("Select * from EMP")
DBCommunicator.DBdisConnect
```

Comment: why don't you try it and let us know if anything goes wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I fixed your code, not sure I agree with it but it seems to work. I don't think VB Script recognizes classes.

```
Option Explicit

'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429313/a-generic-vbscript-function-to-connect-to-any-database-and-execute-any-sql-query
'https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-sql-server-odbc-driver/

Dim oConn, oRst

Public Function DBConnect(StrCon)
    set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    oConn.Open Strcon
    DBConnect = True
End Function

Public Function DBQuery(StrQuery)
    Dim oField
    set oRst = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
    oRst.Open StrQuery, oConn
    Do Until oRst.EOF   
      For each oField in oRst.Fields        
        wscript.echo oField.Name & " = " & oField.Value    
      Next
      oRst.MoveNext
    Loop
End Function

Public Function DBdisConnect
    oRst.close
    oConn.close
End Function


Dim strResult

strResult=DBConnect("<<Connection String of any database User want to connect>>")

If strResult<>True Then
    wscript.echo "DB Connection Failed"
End If

DBQuery("Select * from EMP")

DBdisConnect
```

Answer (score 1):

A routine (Sub or Function) should do exactly one repeatable/reusable task. Your
Function creates, opens, and closes a connection, creates, uses, and closes a
recordset, and annoys the user with message boxes. If you want to do something
sensible tomorrow, you'll have to write (by copy & paste & modify) another
routine.

A Function should return a value; yours doesn't. A Function should have no
side effects; yours does by doing IO. The work/doings of a routine should
be determined by its parameters alone; yours depends on the default settings/values
for the numerous parameters to the .Open methods you don't provide.

Code should not contain fat; .MoveFirst before a .EOF loop, displaying the
.RecordCount in the loop, and setting object variables to Nothing immediately
before the routine's end is just that. VBScript code should start with "Option
Explicit"; yours obviously doesn't.

While independency of a specific DBMS is attractive when you are learning
or investigating, a professional solution for a real world problem should
be based on the decision for the 'best' DBMS for the task; this will lead
to DBMS specific code using DBMS specific features. Then the switch from
one DBMS to another by changing just the ConnectionString is illusionary.

Database work is either of the "connect-do one thing-disconnect" style of
.Net's ADO or of the "connect on start-do many different things-disconnect on
termination" style of 'classical' ADO. If you indicate, what kind of tasks
you have in mind, I may be willing to append to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider creating a DatabaseCommunicator class that does separate database functions (Connect, ExecuteQuery, Disconnect) instead of trying to do everything with one method.  Also if you are wanting to use different types of providers dynamically then you would need to validate the query format to make sure it uses the correct syntax for whatever provider you are using.

I would be very interested in seeing how you accomplish this task should you take it on.

Comment: I will try what you said and will post it in few minutes.